# How do remove labels from 4000+ emails in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I have never used Google Scripts or anything...but is there a quick hack to remove labels from 4000+ emails in my gmail account?

I accidentally put a Filter to attach a certain label to any email that was from myself....and the result was applied to several emails over the years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deleting the label...and creating a new label with the same name using a different Filter criteria in the message body.

Changed from 4000+ mislabelled emails to just 600+.

Seems pretty obvious, but not at the time.